# Append component to end of <p>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a simple page footer in React and TailwindCSS where there is an emoji which shows a tooltip on hover. It looks great when the page is in desktop scaling, however when I test mobile scaling, the emoji doesn't stay appended to the end of the text, it is instead placed next to the whole component and reads as if it is in the middle of the text. Please see images below.

Does anyone know how I can essentially 'glue' this `<Tooltip>` component to the end of the `<p>` component?

The Tooltip component I am trying to use is from the Flowbite-React module: https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/tree/main/src/lib/components/Tooltip

My code:

```js
export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-4/6">
                ....
                <div className="flex w-full justify-center">
                    <p className="dark:text-gray-300 text-black mr-1">© Me test test test, 2022 - Built with ❤️ - Powered by</p> 
                    <Tooltip content="Tooltip text">☕</Tooltip> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Desktop scaling:
[image]

Mobile scaling:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to just put it inside the <p> tag?

Comment: @Shai Unfortunately not. That actually ends up worse... Even in desktop scaling it would render the emoji underneath the rest of the text rather than inline with it

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to figure this out, so to work around it, I have duplicated the code, and reformatted one of the copies to display as I intended. One copy shows when the screen is 'small' or larger, and the newly formatted duplicate will show only on mobile devices.

```js
<div className="w-full justify-center hidden sm:flex">
    <p className="dark:text-gray-300 text-black mr-1 flex-0">© Me test test test, 2022 - Built with ❤️ - Powered by</p> 
    <Tooltip content="Tooltip text">☕</Tooltip>
</div>

<div className="w-full justify-center sm:hidden">
    <p className="dark:text-gray-300 text-black mr-1 flex-0">© Me test test test, 2022 - Built with ❤️</p> 
    <div className="flex">
        <p className="dark:text-gray-300 text-black mr-1 flex-0">Powered by</p>
        <Tooltip content="Tooltip text">☕</Tooltip>
    </div>
                        
</div>
```

Result:

[image]